# How to use OR operator in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, forms, operators

I have a code in which i check a variable value and try to applying OR operator but i failed. My file have edit code. In my scenario i use 4 submit button **Like Save, Submit, Approve and Re-Submit**. Now on Edit File i start a session and apply condition if there is user then show Save and Submit Button but if there is Manager then show Approve and Re-Submit Button. **On Manager Condition i want to apply another if condition that if previous status is Approve then show only Re-Submit Button, if previous status is Save or Submit then Show Both Approve and Re-Submit Button**

Below is my code

```
<?php
include ("session1.php");
?>
<?php
    require 'database.php';
    $id = null;
    if ( !empty($_GET['id'])) {
        $id = $_REQUEST['id'];
    }

    if ( null==$id ) {
        header("Location: index.php");
    }

    //------------------------------------------Update-------------------------------- 
    if ( !empty($_POST)) {
$editor1 =mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['editor1']));
$editor2 =mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['editor2']));
$editor3 =mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['editor3']));
$editor4 =mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['editor4']));
$editor5 =mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['editor5']));
$editor6 =mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['editor6']));
$editor7 =mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['editor7']));
$editor8 =mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['editor8']));
$editor9 =mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['editor9']));
$editor10 =mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['editor10']));
if($_POST['submit'] == "Submit"){
$status=$_POST['submit'];}

if($_POST['submit'] == "Save"){
$status=$_POST['submit'];}


if($_POST['submit'] == "Approve"){
$status=$_POST['submit'];}

if($_POST['submit'] == "Re-Submit"){
$status=$_POST['submit'];}

$valid = true;
        if ($valid) {
            $pdo = Database::connect();
            $sql = "UPDATE test1  set editor1 ='$editor1', editor2 ='$editor2', editor3 ='$editor3',
                                        editor4 ='$editor4', editor5 = '$editor5', editor6 ='$editor6',
                                        editor7 ='$editor7', editor8 ='$editor8', editor9 ='$editor9',
                                        editor10 ='$editor10', status='$status'  WHERE id ='$id'";
            $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $q->execute(array($editor1,$editor12,$editor3,$editor4,$editor5,$editor6,$editor7,$editor8,$editor9,
            $editor10,$status,$id));
            Database::disconnect();
            header("Location: index.php");
        }
}
    else { 
          }

    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","pacra1");

         $id2 = $_GET['id'];
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM test1 where id='$id2'";

            $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

            $row= (mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC));

$editor1 =($row['editor1']);
$editor2 =($row['editor2']);
$editor3 =($row['editor3']);
$editor4 =($row['editor4']);
$editor5 =($row['editor5']);
$editor6 =($row['editor6']);
$editor7 =($row['editor7']);
$editor8 =($row['editor8']);
$editor9 =($row['editor9']);
$editor10 =($row['editor10']);
$status =($row['status']);

    ?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="newstyles.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../jqwidgets/styles/jqx.base.css" type="text/css" /> 
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../../scripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../scripts/demos.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxcore.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxbuttons.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxscrollbar.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxlistbox.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxdropdownlist.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxdropdownbutton.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxcolorpicker.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxwindow.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxeditor.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxtooltip.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxcheckbox.js"></script> 
</head>

<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#editor1').jqxEditor({tools: 'bold italic underline | left center right'
            });

            $('#editor2').jqxEditor({tools: 'bold italic underline | left center right'
            });

            $('#editor3').jqxEditor({tools: 'bold italic underline | left center right'
            });

            $('#editor4').jqxEditor({ 
            });

             $('#editor5').jqxEditor({tools: 'bold italic underline | left center right'
            });
            $('#editor6').jqxEditor({ 
            });
            $('#editor7').jqxEditor({tools: 'bold italic underline | left center right'
            });
            $('#editor8').jqxEditor({tools: 'bold italic underline | left center right'
            });
            $('#editor9').jqxEditor({tools: 'bold italic underline | left center right'
            });
            $('#editor10').jqxEditor({tools: 'bold italic underline | left center right'
            });
            $('#editor11').jqxEditor({
            });

        });
    </script>

    <div style="margin-top: 10px; width: 800px">

    <div style=" margin:auto; width:60px; height:auto; align: middle">
    <img src="image/pacra_logo.png" alt="logo">
    </div>
    <div style="margin:auto; width:auto; text-align:center; font-family:'Times New Roman', Times, serif; font-variant: small-caps; font-size:20px; font-weight:bold">
    The Pakistan Credit Rating Agency Limited 
    <hr></div>
    <form action="edit.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>" method="POST" > 
                <div style="width: 30%; float:left; line-height:0.5" contenteditable="true"><textarea name="editor1" id="editor1"><?php echo(nl2br($editor1));?></textarea>
                </div>
                 <div style="clear: both;"></div>
           <div style=" margin-top:30px; width:35%; float:left; font-family:'Times New Roman', Times, serif; text-align:left; font-size:14px; line-height:0.5" contenteditable="true"><textarea name="editor2" id="editor2"><?php echo(nl2br($editor2));?></textarea></div>
            <div style=" margin-top:30px; margin-left:220px; width:35%; float:left; font-family:'Times New Roman', Times, serif; text-align:right; font-size:14px; line-height:0.5" contenteditable="true"><textarea name="editor3" id="editor3"><?php echo (nl2br($editor3));?></textarea></div>
             <div style="clear: both;"></div>
          <div style="margin-top:40px; margin-right:auto; width:auto; font-family:'Times New Roman', Times, serif; text-align:center; font-variant:small-caps; font-size:18px; font-weight:bold; line-height:0.5" contenteditable="true"><textarea name="editor4" id="editor4"><?php echo(nl2br($editor4));?></textarea></div>
         <div style=" margin-top:20px; width:20%; float:left; font-family:'Times New Roman', Times, serif; text-align:left; font-size:16px; line-height:0.5" contenteditable="true"><textarea name="editor5" id="editor5"> <?php echo(nl2br($editor5));?></textarea></div> 

    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    <div style="margin-top: 10px; width: 800px; text-align:justify; font-family:'Times New Roman', Times, serif; font-size:14px; line-height:0.5" contenteditable="true"><textarea name="editor6" id="editor6"><?php echo (nl2br($editor6));?></textarea></div>

    <div style="margin-top:30px; width:auto; float:left; text-align:left; font-family:'Times New Roman', Times, serif; font-size:16px" contenteditable="true"><textarea name="editor7" id="editor7"><?php echo(nl2br($editor7));?></textarea></div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    <div style="margin-top:100px; width:auto; float:left; text-align:left; font-family:'Times New Roman', Times, serif; font-size:16px; font-variant:small-caps" contenteditable="true"><textarea name="editor8" id="editor8"><?php echo (nl2br($editor8));?></textarea></div>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
    <div style="margin:auto; width:auto; float:left; text-align:left; font-family:'Times New Roman', Times, serif; font-size:16px;" contenteditable="true"><textarea name="editor9" id="editor9"><?php echo(nl2br($editor9));?></textarea></div>    
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    <div style="margin-top:40px; width:auto; height:30px float:left; text-align:left; font-family:'Times New Roman', Times, serif; font-size:16px;" contenteditable="true">
    <textarea name="editor10" id="editor10"><?php echo(nl2br($editor10));?></textarea>
    </div>
    <div style="margin-top:100px">
    <?php

 if($_SESSION['UserName']=='User')
{
?>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
<?php   

    }
    if($_SESSION['UserName']=='Manager')
{
    $_POST['submit']="";

if($_POST['submit'] == "Save" || "Submit")
    {
?>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Approve">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Re-Submit">

<?php   
    }
    }
    else
    {
?>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Re-Submit">
<?php
    }
    ?>


    </div>
    </form>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
    <div style="margin-top:70px; width:800px; float:left; text-align:center; font-family:'Times New Roman', Times, serif; font-size:18px;">
    <hr>
 <strong>Awami Complex FB-1, Usman Block, New Garden Town, Lahore-54600, Pakistan</strong>  
 </br>PABX: 92(42)35869507 Fax: 92(42)35830425 Email: pacra@pacra.com 
 </br>www.pacra.com
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is code in which i face problem

```
<?php 

if($_SESSION['UserName']=='User')
{
?>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
<?php   

    }
    if($_SESSION['UserName']=='Manager')
{
    $_POST['submit']="";

if($_POST['submit'] == "Save" || "Submit")
    {
?>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Approve">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Re-Submit">

<?php   
    }
    }
    else
    {
?>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Re-Submit">
<?php
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: I feel dizzy after reading that paragraph

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky Why you feel Dizzy? Is there any Confusion?

Comment: I think it's a case of "I'm having a problem with this brick, here's the whole house to look at".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are changing `$_POST['submit']` to blank here. Use the code below.

> remove this line `$_POST['submit']="";`
>
> And change the following to

```
<?php
if($_SESSION['UserName']=='Manager')
{

    if($status == 'Approve')
    {
?>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Re-Submit">
    

<?php   
    }
    else
    {
?>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Approve">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Re-Submit">
<?php
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: if i remove $_POST['submit']=" "; then its show an error undefined index submit.

Comment: After checking if user is Manager you should retrieve the value from database to check another condition instead of changing value of `$_POST['submit']`

Comment: Can you tell me the value of `$status`?

Comment: i retrieve the value and also want to change the vale

Comment: The value of $status in name of Submit button. If user Click on Save button then $status value will be save if it click on submit button then value is Submit

Comment: In current scenario the condition is going for manager. So i want to know the value stored in `$status`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83169/discussion-between-pratik-soni-and-sunny).

Answer (score 0):

First remove the line

```
$_POST['submit'] = ""
```

and change

```
if($_POST['submit'] == "Save" || "Submit")
```

to

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && ($_POST['submit'] == "Save" || $_POST['submit'] == "Submit"))
```

Comment: remove the first condition $_POST['submit']=""

Comment: After removing this line it shown an error Notice: Undefined index: submit in C:\xampp\htdocs\MyFirstWebsite\jqwidgets\demos\jqxeditor\edit.php on line 234

Comment: change if($_POST['submit'] == "Save" || $_POST['submit'] == "Submit") to if(isset($_POST['submit']) && ($_POST['submit'] == "Save" || $_POST['submit'] == "Submit"))

Answer (score 0):

You are checking using the OR condition wrongly and you are also resetting the $_POST['submit'] value.  It should be:

```
<?php 

if($_SESSION['UserName']=='User')
{
?>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
<?php   
}

if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_SESSION['UserName']=='Manager')
{
    if($_POST['submit'] == "Save" || $_POST['submit'] == "Submit")
    {
?>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Approve">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Re-Submit">
<?php   
    }
}
else
{
?>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Re-Submit">
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Somewhere else in your code there's an issue then.  Not just where you've said you're having problems.  Is the session variable being set?

Comment: i set session variable `<?php
 
 // starts session
 
 session_start();
 
 // setting variable values during session
 
$_SESSION['UserName']='Manager';
?>`